# Breakpoint not hitting in Flask app in factory pattern VSCode

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug an application in VSCode using the ms-python extension. I have a **flask app** in **factory pattern**. When I try to debug it. The breakpoint doesnot hit when the request comes in. I am using a run file with the code :

```
from flaskapp import *
app = create_app()
app.run(debug=True)
```

my `launch.json` has the following config:

```
{
        "name": "Flask",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/run.py",
        "env": {
            "FLASK_APP": "flaskapp",
            "FLASK_ENV": "development"
        },
        "args": [
            "run",
            // "--no-debugger",
            // "--no-reload"
        ],
        "debugOptions": [
            "RedirectOutput",
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",

        ]
    },
```

Here is a part of code from the module's `__init__.py`

```
def create_app(test_config=None):
  app = Flask(__name__,instance_relative_config=True)
  app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
    )


  if test_config == None:
      app.config.from_pyfile('config.py',silent=True)
  else:
      app.config.form_mapping(test_config)

  try:
      os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
  except OSError:
      pass  

  app.add_url_rule("/<string:name>",'welcome',DataProcessor.welcome)  #with one parameter

  return app
```

I want the breakpoint to hit the `app.add_url_rule` line when the request to that path is made. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Try the experimental debugger to see if that makes a difference. I assume the app runs fine otherwise?

Comment: Any update on this? I'm having the same issue and it's frustrating.

Comment: How about uncomment the "--no-reload" args, that works for me.